# Directing an index of Vector using a pointer, C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have an error appearing that does not allow me to move an index of a Vector to another function using a pointer.

FYI: `vectorTest` has been read from a file containing words and numbers.

Error is underlining `vectorData[0]` and states

> "no suitable user-defined conversion from std::string to std::vector  exists"

Here is the code....

```
class dataInfo
{
private:  

vector <int> idVector; 
vector <string> houseVector;   
vector <string> vectorData;
int idNumber; 
string houseFirst;



public:   

void testClasses(vector <string> vectorTest);
void allocateHouses(vector <string> vectorHouse);  

}; 

void dataInfo::testClasses(vector <string> vectorTest)
{   
    vectorData = vectorTest;


    dataInfo* testPointer = new dataInfo; 

    testPointer->allocateHouses(vectorData[0]); //ERROR IS HERE 
} 

void dataInfo::allocateHouses(vector <string> vectorHouse)
{   
    stringstream ss; 
    ss.str(vectorHouse); 

    while (ss >> idNumber >> houseFirst)
    {
        idVector.push_back(idNumber);
        houseVector.push_back(houseFirst);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < idVector.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << idVector[i] << " " << houseVector[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: What is vectorData and how is it declared? I suspect it is `std::vector<std::vector<something>>`

Comment: You provide us with the code and omit the most crucial detail: the declaration of vectorData. Please fix your code sample

Comment: @Arkadiy problem solved. Was passing the first element of vector into another vector string, when I just needed to pass an 'std::string'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allocateHouse` expects an `std::vector<std::string>`, but since you're passing the first element of the vector via `vectorData[0]`, you're passing just an  `std::string`.
I assume you want to accept just an `std::string` there.
There's also issues regarding unnecessary copies and unnecessary `new` usage.

Comment: thank you, where are the unnecessary copies? the fix seems to work

Comment: If you require parameters such as `std::vector<...>` you actually state that you are going to use your own copy of it. This causes the caller to copy the strings (unless moving). Usually you'd either use a reference via `&` or a constant reference via `const&` in case you don't change the passed data. So in your case `void dataInfo::allocateHouses(string const& vectorHouse)` (same goes for the other method)

Comment: @l3ck just learned about referencing and dereferencing. Thanks a lot for the knowledge shared

Comment: you are welcome